# set height 100% of child div minus fixed height

Tags: html, css

I want the child div height set to 100% minus the height of the header (no scrollbar). Is there a solution without `calc` and without vh and without absolute position? https://jsfiddle.net/y66vz2n7/

```
<html style="height:100%">

<body style="height:100%;background-color:blue;margin:0">

    <div id="parent" style="height:100%; background-color:red;">

        <header style="height:40px;background-color:yellow;">header</header>

        <div id="child" style="height:100%; background-color:green;">child</div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why you don't want to use calc?

Comment: check this idea https://jsfiddle.net/y66vz2n7/3/

Comment: calc and vh are not supported by older browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y66vz2n7/5/)**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {  
    height: 100%;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:0;
}
#child {   
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent" style="height:100%; background-color:red;">
    <header style="height:40px;background-color:yellow;">header</header>
    <div id="child">child</div>
</div>
```

========================================================================

**Update**: **[Demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/y66vz2n7/6/)**

========================================================================

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#parent {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;  
    background-color:red;
}
header {
    display:table-row;
}
.content {
    display: table-row;
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <header style="height:40px;background-color:yellow;">header</header>
    <div class="content">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a solution without absolute position and without vh?

Comment: as you said vh and calc was not supported by prev browser versions. whats wrong with position: absolute.. that will work..

Comment: i have to calculate the top position myself what can be get complicated in more complicated layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution Without Calc()  http://jsfiddle.net/7t0pt09w/

```
CSS : top:40px;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;position:absolute;
```

on the child div will make the div cover the screen and in top give the height of the header